# python psycopg2 can't load the table in the database

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I successfully access the database, however, I can't load the table inside the database. I am quite sure that the name of the table is correct, the database is a mimic iii database. Please give me a helping hand, thanks a lot!

```
import psycopg2

try:
connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                              password="xxxxxxx",
                              host="localhost",
                              port="5432",
                              database="mimic")
cursor = connection.cursor()
postgreSQL_select_Query = "select * from admissions"
cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
print("Selecting rows from mobile table using cursor.fetchall")
admissions_records = cursor.fetchall()

print("Print each row and it's columns values")
for row in admissions_records:
    print("x = ", row[0], )
    print("y = ", row[1])
    print("z  = ", row[2], "\n")

except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
print("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)
finally:
# closing database connection.
if connection:
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

Here's the output:
Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL relation "admissions" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from admissions
^

PostgreSQL connection is closed

Comment: Best bet is you have a case sensitive table name. In `psql` or other client see how `admissions` is actually spelled in the database. Then, if I am correct and is either mixed or upper case you will need to quote it in the query. The name must be quoted with double quotes, so your choices are: `'select * from "Admissions"'` or `"select * from quote_ident('Admissions')"`. See here [String Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) for what the various `quote_*` functions do.

Comment: Next best bet, is that this is a [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) issue. Try schema qualifying the table name: `select * from my_schema.admissions"`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I figure out that it is a search path issue. Your second bet is right! Should I need to do something like upvote to appreciate your contribution? I am an amateur on this website.

Comment: No, this is fairly common issue the answer is also common.